# SQL Server: How to replace carriage return characters

Tags: sql-server, special-characters, string-formatting, carriage-return

I'm using the following procedure to replace all `carriage return` characters  within all tables, with `' + '`:

```
CREATE PROC SearchAndReplace
(
    @SearchStr nvarchar(100),
    @ReplaceStr nvarchar(100)
)
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256), @ColumnName nvarchar(128), @SearchStr2 nvarchar(110), @SQL nvarchar(4000), @RCTR int
    SET  @TableName = ''
    SET @SearchStr2 = QUOTENAME('%' + @SearchStr + '%','''')
    SET @RCTR = 0

    WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @ColumnName = ''
        SET @TableName = 
        (
            SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
            FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
            WHERE       TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
                AND QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
                AND OBJECTPROPERTY(
                        OBJECT_ID(
                            QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)
                             ), 'IsMSShipped'
                               ) = 0
        )

        WHILE (@TableName IS NOT NULL) AND (@ColumnName IS NOT NULL)
        BEGIN
            SET @ColumnName =
            (
                SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME))
                FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                WHERE       TABLE_SCHEMA    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 2)
                    AND TABLE_NAME  = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)
                    AND DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar')
                    AND QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) > @ColumnName
            )

            IF @ColumnName IS NOT NULL
            BEGIN
                SET @SQL=   'UPDATE ' + @TableName + 
                        ' SET ' + @ColumnName 
                        + ' =  REPLACE(' + @ColumnName + ', ' 
                        + QUOTENAME(@SearchStr, '''') + ', ' + QUOTENAME(@ReplaceStr, '''') + 
                        ') WHERE ' + @ColumnName + ' LIKE ' + @SearchStr2
                EXEC (@SQL)
                SET @RCTR = @RCTR + @@ROWCOUNT
            END
        END 
    END

    SELECT 'Replaced ' + CAST(@RCTR AS varchar) + ' occurence(s)' AS 'Outcome'
END
GO
```

After creating the procedure, and calling it as:

`EXEC SearchAndReplace 'GONNA', 'GOING'`

It shows:

> Outcome
>   ---------------------------------------------------- Replaced 148 occurence(s)

And it's the intended result.

---

### Problem:

1. First case:

   Calling `EXEC SearchAndReplace CHAR(10), ' + '` results in the
   following result:

   > Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Server WIN-M6K7U0AQLHJ, Line 1 Incorrect
   >   syntax near '10'.
2. Second case:

   Calling `EXEC SearchAndReplace 'CHAR(10)', ' + '` results in the
   following result:

   > Outcome
   >   ---------------------------------------------------- Replaced 0 occurence(s)
3. Third case:

   Calling `EXEC SearchAndReplace 'CHAR(13)', ' + '` results in the
   following result:

   > Outcome
   >   ---------------------------------------------------- Replaced 0 occurence(s)

Which means the query failed to find the `carriage return` characters and replace them; Although I'm pretty sure, from the `CSV export`, there is unique cells exported as broken into many lines, due to the `carriage return` characters that do obviously exist within the database.

---

I'm new to `SQL Server`, and I can't know exactly what I'm doing wrong.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't use expressions in stored procedure calls. Only literals and variables are allowed. Calling the procedure with the argument `'CHAR(10)'` is allowed, of course, but it searches for the exact string literal `C` `H` `A` `R` `(` `1` `0` `)` -- which obviously isn't present in your data. Note that SQL Server will accept a *literal* carriage return in a string -- as in, press ENTER after the opening `'` -- but that's very confusing for readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to store `Char(10)` value in a variable and then pass that variable as a parameter.

```
declare @tmp varchar(10)=CHAR(10)
EXEC SearchAndReplace @tmp, ' + '
```